# Print output in textfile in java

Tags: java, io, arraylist

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int i;
float[] npoints = new float[10];
float[] points = new float[10];
points[0]=(float) 0.3;
points[1]=(float) 0.2;
points[2]=(float) 0.4;
points[3]=(float) 0.5;
points[4]=(float) 0.6;
points[5]=(float) 0.0123;

for(i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    if(points[i]!=0.0)
    {
        npoints[i]=points[i];
        System.out.println(i+":"+points[i]);
    }

}
System.out.println(npoints[i]);
}
```

output:

```
run:
    0:0.3
    1:0.88
    2:0.22
    3:0.95
    4:0.16
    5:0.0123
[0.95, 0.88, 0.3, 0.22, 0.16, 0.0123]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
`
```

I want to print this output in a textfile, any suggestions? I am new to java

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like [buffered writer](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/)

```
   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileObj);
   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
   bw.write(content);
   bw.close();
```

Comment: it says no suitable method found for write(java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Double>)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `BufferedWriter`:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("somefilename.txt"));
```

Then use the `write` method:

```
bw.write(i+":"+points[i]);  // or bw.write(anything else)
```

Don't forger to close this `BufferedWriter` when you're finished:

```
bw.close();
```

Also, remember to import the appropriate classes from `java.io`, and to handle the `IOException`.

Relevant Javadocs:

- [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)
- [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)
- [IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html)

Comment: when i try to use an arraylist, i.e bw.write(arr), it gives an error,-->no suitable method found for write(java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Double>)

Comment: Yes because the `write` method takes a `String` - try this: `for (double d : arr) bw.write(d + "\n");`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code -- change This is line 1 for what u need to print

```
import java.io.*;

public class WriteText{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       try {
           FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(args[0]);
          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);

          // Also could be written as follows on one line
          // Printwriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[0]));

          // Write text to file
          out.println("This is line 1");
          out.println("This is line 2");
          out.print("This is line3 part 1, ");
          out.println("this is line 3 part 2");
          out.close();
      } catch (IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

}